# PHP Godot Integration

Tags: php, jwt, godot

Is there a way for Godot to use PHP $_SESSION or $_COOKIE globals? I need this because of jwt token auth. When I call API for user login, it gives back token, but I can't use that token in other routes (at least I didn't succeeded) and then embed it in some Godot variable. While I was testing API for fetching token via $_SESSION global, it worked nicely in Postman, but Godot obviously can't read PHP superglobals.

Have anyone had similar problem?

```
http_response_code(200);
$jwt = new JwtHandler();
$token = $jwt->_jwt_encode_data(
             'http://localhost/godot_php',
             array("id" => $row['id'])
);
            
echo json_encode(array('message'=> 'Successfuly logged in!', 'token'=> $token ,'token_expired' => $jwt->expire));
$this->token = $token;
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

This is end of login function where token is stored to session superglobal. Now when I call my second API (from where I should extract token, Godot receives null object).

```
echo json_encode(array('token' => $_SESSION['token']));
```

But if I hardcode string instead of session superglobal, it works fine.

Comment: PHP should export the variable, usually in a cookie (such as the session ID is a cookie value), no other programming language should be able to access PHP internal variables. You want to get the superglobal you need and export it using JSON_encode or similar, for a specific routine on your Godot to collect that data and react accordingly.

Comment: That was precisely what I was doing. When using json_encode with superglobal, postman returns that token nicely in JSON format, but Godot receives NULL object. Really not sure what to do. In the other hand, when I hardcode token in json_encode, Godot picks up that info.

Comment: Please edit your question and update to show what efforts you've tried and what code you're using. That helps us help you by knowing what's already tried and failed. Thank you.

Comment: Just did. Thanks for help tho.

Comment: did you start the session (`session_start();`) on that PHP page?

Comment: Yes, while testing API on Postman, it worked nicely. Don't know if there is some better way of storing and then calling token rather than through session

Comment: Perhaps you can use a standard PHP $_cookie? I am not familiar with Godot.

Comment: I've tried everything that is in my power :) Something will figure out already I hope so. Thanks anyway !